# RealmResult Many-Many Relationship With Adapter

Tags: java, android, realm

I have two models who (with relevant properties) look like this:

#### Playlist.java

```
@PrimaryKey
String id;
String name;
RealmList<Song> songs;
```

#### Song.java

```
@PrimaryKey
String id;
String name;
```

As you can see, a playlist can contain many songs, and a song can belong to many playlists.

In one portion of my app I am displaying all the songs in a RecyclerView with a RealmBaseAdapter. I accomplish this no problem with:

```
RealmResults<Song> songResult = realm.where(Song.class).findAll();
RealmSongsAdapter realmAdapter = new RealmSongsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), songResult , true);
songAdapter.setRealmAdapter(realmAdapter);
```

---

My question is: **how would I go about showing songs for only a certain playlist?** Since Song.java has no reference to it's own playlists, I don't have a way to get a RealmResult based off the Playlist object. Ideally I would like something like:

```
Playlist playlist = realm.where(Playlist.class).equalTo("id", playlistID).findFirst();
RealmResults<Song> playlistSongs = playlist.getSongs();
```

But `playlist.getSongs()` returns a `RealmList<Song>` rather than a `RealmResult<Song>`.

---

One solution I found would be to create a `RealmQuery` based on the Song ids in the playlist, but that seems counter intuitive:

```
RealmQuery<Song> query = mRealm.where(Song.class);
for (Song song : playlist.getSongs()) {
    query = query.or().equalTo("id", song.getId());
}
RealmResults<Song> results = query.findAll();
```

The other problem with this is I would have to re-create this query every time the playlist song list changes.

Is there an easier way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. Currently there is unfortunately no other way than the one you found yourself if you don't want to maintain a `RealmList<Playlist>` field on the `Song`. That said we have a concept called Backlinks on our TODO which are exactly for use cases like this: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'll take a look as the issue.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior but how does adding a backlink to Playlist solve the problem? Because you will still have to query for the Song s of a Playlist instead of simply using the relations between the classes. Do you have in plan to add some support of getting a list of RealmResults from a relation for the case when we have to display that list on the screen? Thanks!